# Site works great in IE9, but with IE8 external scripts are failing to load

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, socket.io, ie8-compatibility-mode

Site:

http://www.compassionpit.com/vent

If you go there in IE9, it will load beautifully.  Yet if you visit in IE8 compatibility mode, it won't even load - at all.

Much gratitude and appreciation for anyone who helps, even leads.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: No errors~! That's the most mysterious aspect.

Comment: How do I articulate a specific question if I don't understand the issue at all?

Comment: @ZacharyBurt You're using WebSockets - those aren't available in IE8 for starters.

Comment: @JonathanSampson that's very helpful.  Now I will go through the code adding log functionality section by section and see if that code is being executed.  Then I will see if I can force other modes of communication.

Comment: @ZacharyBurt Be sure to review [HTML5Please](http://html5please.com/#websockets) and [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) as they may give you some direction. Once you have your plan, feel free to ping the community here with specific questions.

Comment: Personally, I'd just force IE6-8 users to install [Google Chrome Frame](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome-frame/info) plugin in order to use the websockets service, either that or have some headaches with IE fallbacks. `:)`